# jQuery - asp.net mvc- Field is not accepting more than one comma in a sequence of numbers -float numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

For example, if I enter 5,000, the system recognizes as 5,00

Another problem that happens is that if I type, for example 5,100 the system recognizes as null and saves the value as 0.00

I tried everything to understand the problem, but I couldn't

How would I get fields to recognize values entered with commas or dots?

My code:

```
public class EstoqueDaEmbarcacao : Entity
{
    public decimal AguaCarregada { get; set; }

    public decimal DieselCarregado { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery

```
function fillInventoryData(barcoId) {
    $("#estoque-barco-id").val(barcoId);
    $("#estoque-barco-nome").val($("#selectEmbarcacao option:selected").text());
    $("#modal-estoque").modal('show');
}
function saveInventory() {
    $("#message-estoque").removeClass("alert-danger");
    $("#message-estoque").removeClass("alert-warning");
    var barcoId = $("#estoque-barco-id").val();
    var agua = $("#estoque-barco-agua").val().replace(",", ".");
    var diesel = $("#estoque-barco-diesel").val().replace(",", ".");
    var data = JSON.stringify({ AguaCarregada: agua, DieselCarregado: diesel, BarcoId: barcoId });
    if (agua == "" || diesel == "") {
        $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-warning");
        $("#message-estoque").html("Fill in all fields to continue");
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/InfoApontamento/AtualizarEstoqueBarco",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {

            if (!result.Success) {

                $("#message-estoque").html(result.ErrorDatail);
                $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-danger");
            }
            else if (!result.Data) {
                $("#message-estoque").html(result.Message);
                $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-danger");
            }
            else {
                alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
                $("#modal-estoque").modal('hide');
                $('#estoque-barco-agua').val("");
                $('#estoque-barco-diesel').val("");
                // abrirModalManutencao();
                preInicializarModal();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Page:

```
<div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="embarcacaoInput">Água</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="estoque-barco-agua">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="embarcacaoInput">Diesel</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="estoque-barco-diesel">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ AguaCarregada: agua, DieselCarregado: diesel, BarcoId: barcoId });
```

for this (parseFloat()):

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ AguaCarregada: parseFloat(agua), DieselCarregado: parseFloat(diesel), BarcoId: barcoId });
```

Comment: Hernandez The problem continues, the system still ignores the number of 0's after the comma and also does not accept nonzero numbers after the comma.